# collada External Reference

Tags: reference, external, collada

When I load the samples with viewer by collada dom 1.4.
externalRef.dae

```
 <library_nodes>
  <node>
       <instance_geometry url="cube.dae#box-lib"/>
  </node>
</library_nodes>
```

I tried many loaders of collada like glc_player,google sketchUp,but none of them succeed.
what is wrong?

Comment: Specifically, I am looking to find proper syntax needed in the collada assembly dae file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of [pycollada](https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada), and I've had extensive experience with the COLLADA format.

External references in COLLADA were a good idea, but there's almost no support for it across the set of libraries and tools available today. If you want to use external references in your own tools, that's fine, but you're breaking compatibility with almost every tool that imports COLLADA.

There's been some effort to fix issues like this with the [COLLADA Conformance Test Suite](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA-CTS), but there's hasn't been much adoption yet.

Comment: Does pycollada support loading external references?

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc: [vandaengine doc](http://vandaengine.com/exporting-from-maya/) OpenCOLLADA import/export should have support for external references, so does the vandaengine. I did not try this myself.